# MYSQL : Manual simulation of the triggering event

Tags: mysql, triggers, insert, simulate

MYSQL:

I have a table with a AFTER INSERT ON trigger on it.

I have inserted a million rows in the table and the trigger code successfully gets executed and updates 10 other tables.

Now, I have deleted the data from the 10 children tables but the million rows in the parent table is retained.

Can I manually simulate that trigger code for those million records in the parent table to reinsert them in the 10 children tables...???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can't. Only actual, successful `INSERT`s trigger before/after insert triggers.

Comment: Thanks, now i have to drop that table and load one more time which takes like 30 mins in my environment. But, your confirmation helped.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "AFTER INSERT" trigger like an "AFTER UPDATE", then you can make a safe update where you don't harm anything, this way you can re insert the rows.

Don't forget to delete "AFTER UPDATE", and restore de respective "AFTER INSERT".